# Salesforce1-specific navigation issue, sforce not defined in browser S1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm trying to use the Salesforce documented method for determining if we're in the Salesforce1 UI when viewing a page in my app but for some reason, this code is not working the browser version of Salesforce (one/one.app)

```
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
    // Salesforce1 navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
```

sforce is not defined in /one/one.app ... Any ideas?

Comment: I assume your running that code in a VF page embedded in S1 right?

Comment: Also your check is a little off, it should be && sforce.one != null) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I wasn't able to find sforce in my console was because the Visualforce page is inside of an iframe. I needed to change the context of the console to operate from the frame rather than the top frame in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing by the docs :

Are you trying to run the app in your browser : may be this could be the reason why it is not working

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/index_Left.htm#CSHID=vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fvf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm|SkinName=webhelp

> The if statement checks to see if the sforce object is available and
>   usable. **This is only true if the page is running inside
>   Salesforce1.**
>
> If the sforce object isn’t available, trying to use it to navigate
>   anywhere results in a JavaScript error, and no navigation

Comment: Salesforce1 is both a browser app (one/one.app) and a native mobile app, so I would expect the Javascript API to be available in both places.

Comment: how are you trying to access you app on the browser are you using instance/one/one.app

Comment: did you enable saleseforce1 app access on desktop. check out : http://jessealtman.com/2013/12/working-with-salesforce1-on-the-desktop/

Comment: that's correct (/one/one.app), the browser container for Salesforce1

Comment: I'm clearly inside of Salesforce1 visual container, it has been enabled on the desktop.